# Automate Date Of Birth select element

Tags: php, html, select

When making a contact form in html/PHP (either) its a pain to sit there and type out all days, months and years into the select element. Is there a for loop or anything that can speed this process up, anything to avoid hardcoding this everytime?

Comment: why not consider the a calender option? ther are some nice jquery calender function, date pickers

Comment: copy and paste from another site, save it and reuse

Comment: -1, if you do not know how to use functions etc., you should be reading basics of programming, not asking questions like this

Comment: And i here i thought this was a Q&A site, what a dumbass

Comment: @peenut: just because this is a very easy question (for you and me - but in fact it's a matter of opinion), this doesn't mean it isn't worth being asked here.

Comment: @benhowdle89 It's not unreasonable to expect you to make your best effort before asking for someone to give you code for free.

Comment: I can accept that lonesomeday but peenut wasnt exactly constructive in his comment, he assumed i knew nothing because i was asking this question

Comment: @benhowdle I think many of us assumed the same. Writing such a loop is *extremely* trivial and something you should be able to do long before you start building websites.

Comment: @benhowdle That said, I don't think he should have downvoted your question for being too simple. I do think you should take his advice though, and pick up a book on programming, in *any* language. Some fundamentals will help you out a lot.

Comment: I think this has been taken way out of context, i can program, i have 2 iPhone apps and many websites out there. this question was something i was curious about, having never taken the time to put thought to it. So yes, it was laziness to ask the question and it will be useful for other people to see the answer but its not through lack of ability i asked it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for **days**:

```
<?php
$days = range(1, 31);
?>
```

for **months**:

```
<?php
$months = range(1, 12);
?>
```

for **years**:

```
<?php
$years = range(1930, date('Y'));
?>
```

**EDIT:**
And use it like that:

```
<select name="day">
<?php
foreach($days as $day) {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo($day) ?>"><?php echo($day) ?></option>
<?
}
?>
</select>
```

and so on ... ;-)

Comment: what if user chooses the 31 of February?

Comment: @naneri Check back after selection when you only want to use serverside code. Otherwise it would be possible to check back with JavaScript or a JS library like jQuery. If a user selects a month with only 30 days the day value decreases to 30 days and so on ;-)...

Answer (score 3):

How about a [jQuery driven date picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)?

Comment: jQuery and jQuery UI are *huge* dependencies to add to a project for the sake of a date picker. Plus, I'd rather have something that works for everybody, not just users with JS enabled.

Comment: Why cater to people without JS enabled? The only way to make them change is to stop coddling them. See also: IE 6 support.